# Timing Concurrent CUDA Kernels

Tags: cuda

Unfortunately fermi based GPU's will trace any kernel timing as being serialized in Parallel Nsight, even if they are concurrent kernels in different streams.

Can anyone suggest how to show concurrency of kernels in different streams manually using timers.

Cheers
Ed

Answer (score 2):

Profiling with Nsight does currently disable concurrent kernels, so to get accurate timing you'll need to use events to track timing.

You can use events as you'd expect, and you can use `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` to make a stream wait for an event in another stream. See the [CUDA Reference Manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Reference_Manual.pdf) section 4.5.2.5 for more information.

Comment: Profiling no longer disables concurrent kernel execution these days.